Is there different types of transfers?
What I am basically asking is, does transfering tokens/sol directly from your phantom wallet to another wallet count as a different transfer opposed to if you were to do it with a smart contract or code? If yes, will the difference be shown on solscan or can be seen somewhere?

There isn't any difference.
If you are still the authority, it'll just be your token being routed through the token program making a CPI call to the token program to transfer your asset

yes and no. The transfer itself is the same. However, if you do it from a program, you can see that it was done from a program on solscan, because each instruction is linked to a program id, and you can see that the said program id is a custom program (non native). But in javascript we can code the exact same transfer than the one in phantom, no one could see the difference.
If you want to provide a tx signature, i can show you what i mean, it would be easier
